# Cannot resolve android.support.v4.view.Menu

Tags: android

So I was building this older version of Ushahidi and one of the classes that extends `FragmentMapActivity` requires to import `android.support.v4.view.Menu` for overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

But I cannot find such support library that contains this Menu class. It cannot use `android.view.Menu` because `FragmentMapActivity implements onCreateOptionsManu(android.view.Menu menu)` as final.

So Where can I get `android.support.v4.view.Menu` or is there's some ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dependency `com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0` to **build.gradle** of your application

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    ...
}
```